# How to embed PDFs that work in all web and mobile browsers

Tags: php, javascript, html, pdf

My client asked me to create a page which contains PDF. I used Embed, Iframe tags, it worked in Mozilla but did not work in IE and Mobile browser.

I know that all browsers will read .pdf directly but I want it to be embed.

Is there any way?

Please help me..

Comment: per @VSU's answer, you can't really _embed_ PDF's like you can images or videos - it's not part of the HTML spec or standard browser implementations.  You'll need to convert the pdf to HTML or raster images if you want the _content_ truly integrated into a web page.

Answer (score 8):

If you give a link to the PDF on the web page, any browser will be able to download the file and then the user can open it in a PDF viewer of his choice.

If you want to embed the PDF document in a web page, then the browser needs to have a PDF plugin installed. This may not be the case with all browsers. The PDF will be displayed only if the PDF viewer application's plugin is registered with the browser.

The other way of embedding the PDF document is to use a server-side component that renders the PDF as ordinary HTML web page elements. Google has [an embeddable PDF viewer](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html).

> Google Docs offers an
> undocumented feature that lets you
> embed PDF files and PowerPoint
> presentations in a web page. The files
> don't have to be uploaded to Google
> Docs, but they need to be available
> online.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Mozilla's [pdf renderer](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) written in javascript. It is rather complex getting started, but all options are there. It is the pdf reader available in Firefox and extensions exist for other browsers. Fun fact: It is by far the most starred library on github when searching for pdf.

Answer (score -2):

Try using adobe pdf api, i found is very easy and compatible with all browsers.
https://www.adobe.io/apis/documentcloud/dcsdk/pdf-embed.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

here is best solution to embed even large pdf in your html/php or any language.its also work on any mobile.

1. Login to Adobe console
2. create project
3. enable adobe pdf embed api (Its free)
4. copy client id
   below is php code to embed pdf

   ```
   <div id="adobe-dc-view" style="width: 800px;"></div>
   <script src="https://acrobatservices.adobe.com/view-sdk/viewer.js">     
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   document.addEventListener("adobe_dc_view_sdk.ready", function(){ 
   var adobeDCView = new AdobeDC.View({clientId: "<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>", divId: "adobe-dc-view"});
   adobeDCView.previewFile({
       content:{location: {url: "<?= $pdffile ?>"}},
       metaData:{fileName: "<?=$magazine['name']?>"}
   }, {});
   });
   </script>
   ```

Comment: "*here is best solution*" - This is subjective

Comment: @Jacob you dont see <?=$magazine['name']?>?
is it not php?