# Display pdf generated using mpdf inline in mobile browsers

Tags: php, google-chrome, internet-explorer, pdf, mpdf

Is there any way to display pdf generated using mpdf inline in mobile browsers?

I went through [mpdf documentation](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/output.html) and tried destination option `mpdf->output('filename.pdf','I')`. It works pretty well across every browser in desktop except IE and doesn't work in mobile-browsers like Firefox, Chrome etc. It starts downloading automatically instead of displaying inline in IE in desktop and all mobile browsers.

Anyways to handle this?

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/cant-view-pdf-web.html ?

Comment: Based on library code, looks like a client side issue. As there are no any browser specific headers that it sets. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mpdf/mpdf/development/src/Mpdf.php. Search for `case Destination::INLINE:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I stumbled upon this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137457/how-to-embed-pdfs-that-work-in-all-web-and-mobile-browsers). You can also try Google [embeddable PDF Viewer](https://googlesystem.blogspot.in/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html)

As per the blog:

> Google Docs offers an undocumented feature that lets you embed PDF files and PowerPoint presentations in a web page. The files don't have to be uploaded to Google Docs, but they need to be available online.

Comment: Rishabh, I tried this and works pretty well in my case without using third-party library. Thanks for the suggestion and the stackoverflow post.

Answer (score 3):

based on documentation : 
I: send the file inline to the browser. The plug-in is used if available. The name given by $filename is used when one selects the “Save as” option on the link generating the PDF.

You need plug-in installed on your browser to embed the PDF document (Desktop and Mobile). If your browser doesn't has PDF Viewer plug-in, PDF document will be downloaded automatically.

You can use Javascript plugin such as [pdfJs](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js) to embed your PDF document in cross browsers.

Comment: Muhammad, I have already tried pdfJS, ViewerJS and it works well with it. I was wondering if it can be achieved with mpdf itself!