# How to display embedded PDF in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, angular

I am using embed tag to display pdf file on my browser. But it can't display in IE. How to show it in all browsers. Thanks

```
I using html, angular 4....
my code:
<div class="modal-content" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <embed type="application/pdf" [src]="item.url" frameborder="0"</embed>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21340820/pdf-embed-not-working-in-ie11-but-it-works-when-edit-the-html-in-dom-explorer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to embed PDFs that work in all web and mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137457/how-to-embed-pdfs-that-work-in-all-web-and-mobile-browsers)

Comment: I tried. But it not working

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<embed [src]="item.url" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px" />
```

you can take a look in this page: https://www.codexworld.com/embed-pdf-document-file-in-html-web-page/